# When is my piversary?

Tags: code-golf, date, pi

Since I want to celebrate this definitely not nerdy event, your job is to calculate the piversary (pi-anniversary) of a given date.

#### Input

Your code has to have a possibilty to input a date in the format `DD/MM/YYYY`. You can expect, that the input is valid and the year is `0000<YYYY<9996`.

#### Output

You have to release two dates, the date in Pi months and the date in Pi years.

#### Rules

- If your language hasn't a build in Pi, you have to make a variable which will be exact enough to calculate the dates, but it is not allowed to calculate the days separately and use fix numbers.
- You have to take care, that the months have different amount of days, but you don't have to care about leap years (only if you want).
- If you calculate the date, you have to add the three years/months first and then the left part in rounded days.
- Your code has to accept **any** valid date and should be able to handle edge cases like `30/12/2000`

Example:

```
Input: 12/04/2010

Calculate monthly piversary:
date +  3 months = 12/07/2010
date + (31*(Pi-3)) = date + 4.39 = date + 4 = 16/07/2010 //31 because July has 31 days

Calculate yearly piversary:
date + 3 years = 12/04/2013
date + (365*(Pi-3)) = date + 52 = 03/06/2013

Output:
16/07/2010,03/06/2013
```

**May the shortest code win.**

Comment: [xkcd.com/1179](http://xkcd.com/1179/)

Comment: Are leading zeroes required in the output?

Comment: @Zaq Awesome picture :) I will use it next time, I promise.

Comment: @hsl Yes they are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Mathematica, <s>152</s> 134 bytes

```
f[i_]:=DateList@{i,{d="Day",m="Month",y="Year"}}~DatePlus~{{3,#},{Round[#2*(Pi-3.)],d}}~DateString~{d,"/",m,"/",y}&@@@{{m,31},{y,365}}
```

Ungolfed

```
f[i_] :=
 DateString[
    DatePlus[
     DateList@{i,{d="Day",m="Month",y="Year"}}, 
     {{3, #}, {Round[#2*(Pi - 3.)], d}}
    ],
    {d, "/", m, "/", y}
 ] & @@@ {{m, 31}, {y, 365}}
```

This does handle leap years. It's also horribly long.

Answer (score 1):

## MATLAB: 141 <s>157, 169</s>

```
o='DD/mm/YY'
d=datenum(x,o) 
f=@(s,v) datestr(addtodate(addtodate(d,3,s),(pi-3)*v,'day'),o)
f('year',365)
f('month',eomday(year(d),month(d)))
```

Quite long and straightforward. It assumes the input to be in `x`.

---

Here is a version that is a few chars longer for those without the financial toolbox:

```
o='DD/mm/YY'
d=datenum(x,o) 
[y,m]=datevec(d)
f=@(s,v) datestr(addtodate(addtodate(d,3,s),(pi-3)*v,'day'),o)
f('year',365)
f('month',eomday(y,m))
```

Answer (score 1):

### Groovy - 297 chars

Uses Joda Time. Does not handle leap years.

Golfed:

```
@Grab(group='joda-time', module='joda-time', version='2.3')
f=org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy")
t=f.parseDateTime(args[0])
p="plusDays"
m="Month"
println f.print(t."plus${m}s"(3)."$p"((t."dayOf$m"().maximumValue*(Math.PI-3)) as int))+","+f.print(t.plusYears(3)."$p"(52))
```

Sample run:

```
$ groovy Pi.groovy 12/04/2010
16/07/2010,03/06/2013

$ groovy Pi.groovy 30/12/2000
03/04/2001,20/02/2004
```

Ungolfed:

```
@Grab(group='joda-time', module='joda-time', version='2.3')

f = org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy")

t = f.parseDateTime(args[0])

println f.print(t.plusMonths(3).plusDays((t.dayOfMonth().maximumValue*(Math.PI-3)) as int)) 
        + "," +
        f.print(t.plusYears(3).plusDays(52))
```